# Gradle Downloading Error

Tags: android, gradle, download

I am using android studio 3.1 I tried to create a new project, but android studio stuck at the point illustrated in the picture:

[image: While creating project]

After that It also giving these errors:

[image: After finishing with error]

[Errors:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCTFL.png)

**Note that** my internet connection is good and Gradle offline mode unchecked

Comment: just open the file and put your gradle file code here

Comment: Could you clarify in detail please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaIOi.png

Your snapshot says `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1.`
 It looks like your dependency is wrong, 
try using this below line in your gradle file and sync:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is in offline mode, which means that it won't go to the network to resolve dependencies.

Go to File -> Settings.

And open the 'Build,Execution,Deployment',Then open the 'Build Tools' -> 'Gradle'.

Then uncheck "Offline work" on the right.

Click the 'OK' button.

Then Rebuild the Project.

For Mac go to AndroidStudio -> Preferences, rest is same.